# System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'password'

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

My code has a database connection health monitor mechanism which checks the database connection state and if the connection is broken, it tries to reconnect after every 30 seconds. During the retries, it uses a SqlConnection object and assigns a connection string to the object before calling the Open method. The relevant function is as follows.

```
public int Open(DBConnectionMode ConnectionMode, string server, string database, string user, string password) 
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlconbuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        sqlconbuilder.DataSource = server;
        sqlconbuilder.InitialCatalog = database;

        if ((server != string.Empty) && (user == string.Empty))
            sqlconbuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        else
            sqlconbuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        sqlconbuilder.UserID = user;
        sqlconbuilder.Password = password;

        if (ConnectionMode == DBConnectionMode.LOCAL)
        {
            // oConnection is of type SqlConnection
            oConnection.ConnectionString = sqlconbuilder.ConnectionString; 
            oConnection.Open();
        }
        else
        {
            oConnectionRemote.ConnectionString = sqlconbuilder.ConnectionString;  
            oConnectionRemote.Open();

        }
        //update global connected indicator
        if (oCommand.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            isConnected = true;
        else
            isConnected = false;

        return 0;
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex) 
    {
        return (int)DBErrorCode.CONNECTION_OPEN_INVALID_PARAMS;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) 
    {
        return (int)DBErrorCode.CONNECTION_ERROR;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw (ex);
    }

}
```

The connection string returned by the sqlconbuilder.ConnectionString is as follows.

```
Data Source=UK-NHAM-2016-01;Initial Catalog=ArcPubCfg;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxx
```

During first few retries nothing goes wrong, but then I start getting following error.

```
System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'password'
```

I have narrowed down the error to this line of code.

```
oConnection.ConnectionString = sqlconbuilder.ConnectionString;
```

I have confirmed that the connection string remains same. Once I start getting this error, it continues to fail on this line. I re-create every relevant object again during each retry but the result is same.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

**Edit:** An interesting thing is that the issue does not happen when the SQL server is stopped at the time of startup of my application. My application continues the retries and does not encounter this error. Once the database connection is established and then it breaks afterwards, the retry mechanism starts getting this error after a while.

Comment: Are disposing of your connection, etc properly using `using` statements?

Comment: Either way we'll need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: What is the connection string in your config? Can you share it securely without any ip, pass or id information?

Comment: @pegasuspect connection string is in the question

Comment: I know It is the one "returned" from the object constructer. I am talking about your configuration.

Comment: @nauman73 what is your web.config looks like for the line connection string?

Comment: What type is `oConnection`?

Comment: @Liam The oConnection is a class member. I have tried disposing it before each connection attempt but the issue remains. I have now added complete code of my Open function in the question.

Comment: @pegasuspect Connection string is constructed at run time and not read from config. I have now added complete code of the function which constructs the connection string and then attempts to open a connection.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen 'oConnection' is SqlConnection type.

Comment: Have you verified what the resulting connection string looked like?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Connection string is given in the question. I have taken the connection string from the logs of my application.

Answer (score 0):

After some head scratching I managed to solve the problem.

Basically the **Open** function in my question was being called from a thread function after every 30 seconds to attempt to restore the database connection. The thread function was running a while loop with a **Thread.Sleep(30000)**. I have now changed this to a timer (**System.Timers.Timer**) instead of a thread function. The timer fires after every 30 seconds to invoke the **Open** function. This has solved the issue.

I still do not know why the issue actually occurred and why my solution has fixed this. But as long as it works, I am happy.

Comment: With some further testing, this solution is not working for cases where the SQL Server is not on same machine as my application. If there is a network disconnection between my application machine and the SQL Server machine, I start getting the same exception that is mentioned in my original question. So unmarking my above answer as accepted answer.